# R plotting annual data and "January" repeated at end of graph

Tags: r, date, plot

I'm fairly new to R and am trying to plot some expenditure data.  I read the data in from excel and then do some manipulation on the dates

```
data <- read.csv("Spending2019.csv", header = T)

#converts time so R can use the dates

strdate <- strptime(data$DATE,"%m/%d/%Y")
newdate <- cbind(data,strdate)    
finaldata <- newdate[order(strdate),]
```

This probably isn't the most efficient, but it gets me there :)

Here's the relevant columns of the first four lines of my finaldata dataframe

```
dput(droplevels(finaldata[1:4,c(5,7)]))
structure(list(AMOUNT = c(25.13, 14.96, 43.22, 18.43), strdate = structure(c(1546578000, 
1546750800, 1547010000, 1547010000), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = "")), row.names = c(NA, 4L), class = "data.frame")
```

The full data set has 146 rows and the dates range from 1/4/2019 to 12/30/2019
I then plot the data

```
plot(finaldata$strdate,finaldata$AMOUNT, xlab = "Month", ylab = "Amount Spent")
```

and I get this plot

[image]

This is fine for me getting started, EXCEPT why is JAN repeated at the far right end?  I have tried various forms of xlim and can't seem to get it to go away.

Comment: It's repeated because it is January of the next year. The fact that you "know" that it should only be one year's worth of data is just you, to R the default method is to provide an indication of what is at that tick. The solution has you telling `plot` to not add x-ticks and then you doing it yourself with `axis`.

Comment: You may check the range of dates in your data by using the range function>
range(finaldata$strdate)

Comment: I understood that R was adding the tick but I don't know how to tell it not to...I'll google the usage of axis